# Javascript to select checkbox

Tags: javascript, html

What would be the javascript below to select the checkbox for value 0?

`<input name="bootproto" id="bootproto" type="radio" value="0" key="bootproto">`

I tried using

`$('input[name="bootproto"]').click()` but it didnt seem to work.

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ZS2AF/

Comment: Are you actually using jQuery? You didn't include it in your tags. And that jQuery line won't work if you're not using/haven't loaded it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that `$('input[value="0"]').click()` seemed to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#bootproto").prop("checked",true);
```

Since you're using jquery, just set the property "checked" to true (I don't see why you're name selecting when you have a perfectly good ID there as well)

If you want to check it ONLY if value=0, add an if statement before this.

Answer (score 0):

```
 document.getElementById('bootproto').checked = true;
```

OR

```
 $('#bootproto').prop('checked',true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$('input[name="bootproto"]').attr('checked',true);
```

`Checked` is actually an `attribute` of the `input` tag of type `radio`, So that you can use the **[.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)** function to set its checked attribute as `true`.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZS2AF/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention that you're using jQuery even tho you've apparently tried the syntax. On the off-chance you're *not* using it, try:

```
var i = document.querySelector('input[value="0"]').checked = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following : `$('input[name="bootproto"]:not(:checked)')`.